# Publish Web Page on Local Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, iis, gridview

I have a Web App developed in Visual Studio Community 2019 utilizing  ASP.NET, C# and HTML. I am trying to Publish the App locally so that it can be accessed by other Computer systems within the same server. I can successfully publish the static data (images, boxes, headings, titles, etc.) but the DataGrid on my web page does not displays any data.

I connected the data via connectionString to SSMS which works perfectly via IIS Express, if I run the application by opening Visual Studio. I am looking for a way where I don't require to open and Run the application and all computers within the same server can access it directly.

Comment: Keep in mind the differences, https://blog.lextudio.com/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3

Comment: Could you please post your connection string? I guess you may use sql express as the database.

Comment: <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source= TestServer;Initial Catalog=DataBase1;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

Comment: As far as I know, if you host the application on the IIS, it will use the application pool identity as the user account to access the sql server. Normally we will modify the application pool identity to a specific user which could access the sql server. More details about how to modify it ,you could refer to this [Image](https://s3.amazonaws.com/cdn.freshdesk.com/data/helpdesk/attachments/production/5071350145/original/NetworkIdentity.png?1474416511).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using SQL Server (User name/password) authentication in connection string instead of Windows Authentication if not already done.

Also you can add the 'IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool' user as a database user in your SQL instance, then providing the proper 'User Mappings' to the databases you need the DefaultAppPool user to access.

Comment: It is Windows Authenticated Only